# PHP: Why I Can Only Download 16 KB (16624 Bytes) Of The Files About 8M by PHP echo?

Tags: php, file-get-contents, output-buffering

I use `file_get_contents()` to read a file larger than 7M (7 - 30M). And then I echo it to let the clients download it.

Note: there's no direact link for downloading these files. So I have to read it into PHP, and make a download file. Read a large file into memory is absolutely a wrong idea --- The best way is to make the file a direact download link. But not now...Coz the file is created by others, and they don't have plan to move them to our cloud-file servers. --- So I have to handle it by PHP.

There's something weired. It works well on my personal PHP7 docker container ( the config file is here: https://github.com/AarioAi/Conf )

I can download the full file ( maybe 7.8M).

But when I push these codes to another server (PHP 5.5) which has almost the same PHP and Nginx configs. I can only download 16KB(16624B) of this file.

Here's the debug information about the 7.8M binary file:

```
"HTTP_RANGE": null,
"Content-Length:": 7490833,
"md5": "aaefc8249e2a96574fa7b83e7bc168f0",
"fileSize": 7490833
```

In order to check whether the 16KB segment is a part of the original file. I fill a 16M file with repeated string "Hello, Aario." by shell script. Then I open the downloaded 16KB segment from the PHP 5.5 server. They are all "Hello, Aario. Hello, Aario. ....."

So the 16KB is definitely the segment of the original file.

Here's the debug information about the 16M "Hello, Aario.":

```
"HTTP_RANGE": null,
"Content-type": "application/force-download",
"Content-Length:": 16155228,
"md5": "5c919dd9d1049a59e7c2a8cb55a695a9",
"fileSize": 16155228
```

I send nothing to the ob_xxx, so I think there's nothing wrong with `output_buffering` config. The PHP `memory_limit` configs are the same on both servers. And I also notice that there's no significant diffirence between the php-fpm.conf files.

I guess it may be timeout. I check the Nginx `keepalive_timeout` on the another server (PHP 5.5), it's `65` which is longer than on this server (PHP 7).

So could you give me some tips?

```
 //---------------------------------------------------------------------
 $length = (function_exists('mb_strlen') ? mb_strlen($content, '8bit') : strlen($content));
 // it's just the sample to calculate Content-Length, actually, 
 // it needs be handled in the if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE'])) {}
 //----------------------------------------------------------------------

 if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE'])) {
        header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');
        //client sent us a multibyte range, can not hold this one for now
        if (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE'], ',') !== false) {
            header("Content-Range: bytes $contentStart-$contentEnd/$fileSize");
   ....
   ....
 }



 if ($debug > 0) {
        return [
            'Content-type' => $contentType,
            'Content-Length:' => $length,
            'md5' => md5_file($file),
            'fileSize' => $fileSize,
        ];
    } else {
        header('Pragma: public');
        header('Expires: 0');
        header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
        header("Content-Type: $contentType");
        header('Content-Length: ' . $length);
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$fileName\"");
        header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
        $content = function_exists('mb_substr') ? mb_substr($content, $contentStart, $length) : substr($content, $contentStart, $length);
        ob_start();
        ob_end_clean();
        echo $content;
        exit(0);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't see how the piece of code you show could work. It doesn't. For one, there's no `file_get_contents()` in it. And what does this do?

```
    ob_start();
    ob_end_clean();
```

Nothing? There are also a lot of variables which are not define. In short, this is a bad example.

Reading larger files with `file_get_contents()` and then `echo` it, is, in my opion, not a good idea. The whole file will be read to memory, stored there, before it can send to the output. Traditionally files have always been read in chunks, and then send in chunks to the output.

A better way to stream a file to the output is this:

```
// open the file in a binary mode
$filename = '/mybigfile.huge';
$handle   = fopen($filename,'rb');

if ($handle)
{
  // send the right headers
  header("Content-Type: .....");
  header("Content-Length: " . filesize($filename ));
  ........

  // dump the file to the output
  fpassthru($handle);
  // close file
  fclose($handle);
}
```

Comment: ob_start()  ... You can google it. And I want to allow the client send HTTP_RANGE.

Comment: My point is: `ob_start();`, directly followed by `ob_end_clean();`, does exacly nothing. You can leave it out, and the result will be the same. As to `HTTP_RANGE`: My code is a short example, you can expand it anyway you want.

Comment: I tried fopen before, but it was as same as `echo $content`.  Read a large file into memory is absolutely a wrong idea --- The best way is to make the   file to a direact download link. But not now...Coz the file is created by others, and they don't have plan to move them to our cloud-file servers. --- So I have to handle it by PHP. I tried fpassthru, it's same, only 16KB can be downloaded from the PHP 5.5 Server while 7.8M from the PHP7.

Comment: You give more information in your comment than in your question. The file is not yours, it's external. This is a very important point. I was confused by your explanation of that (no link, have to download it with PHP). I now believe that your problem has nothing to do with PHP, but rather with the source of the file, and how your server interacts with it. Exactly how I cannot know.

Comment: These files are in another directory other than the Nginx server root. I can only read there files. ( I can't write and execute). It's on the same server to PHP  --- I appy to upload these files to our cloud-file servers and I'll contact with the staff who create these files to handle it next week (change the database and notify the others to change new links). --- Fine, I'll not use PHP to read these files. But  I still want to know why I can only read 16KB(absotely a part from that file) from that server, but 7.8M(100%) from my server with the same code?

Comment: If it is a local file, to which you have read acces (= permission to read), then I cannot think of any reason why the 16KB limit should occurs. You could inspect the content of the file to see if the 16 KB are really the beginning of the file, or if it is something else.

Comment: I can 100% sure that the 16KB file is really a part of the beginning of the source file.

Comment: When you use `$content = file_get_contents(...);` in PHP and then `echo count($content);`, does it also report 16KB? Or similary; `echo filesize(...);`. In other words: Is it the reading of the file or the outputting which is the problem?

Comment: the `Content-Length` above is strlen($content). it's same as filesize() ...  you can trace the debug informations above.

Comment: I understand, the info was there, sorry. So the string does contain the content of the file, but, regardless of which output method you use, the output is limited to 16 KB. I have no idea what could cause this, it should not happen.